# RAID Controller Firmware Issue

Tags: ubuntu, raid, bios, megaraid, hba

**Background:** I'm a Linux newbie with very limited knowledge, I wanted to build a RAID 10 for our startup after experiencing a complete loss of several terabytes of data from Dropbox recently.

**Setup:** I spun up an Ubuntu 16.04 (Desktop) machine and installed an LSI-2008-8E RAID controller, I connected this to our JBOD via two mini-SAS cables. Intel i7, 16gb RAM, Samsung SSD. Barebones. RAID Controller is on PCI slot 1.

**Issue:** Upon installing the card and booting up the entire system, the drives were able to be identified, everything was fine. I went to install the drivers that came with the RAID card, but seeing as how I have very limited knowledge of Linux I turned to online tutorials that led me to MegaRAID Software Manager, an application with a GUI. I opted for this over MDADM (not sure why now).

These tutorials also led me to install several other items which I can't remember now, this resulted in installing something called **MPT SAS2 BIOS**

I don't remember installing this, nor do I know what it does. I'm assuming this is something that was accidentally installed in the boot folder to assign the boot priority to the RAID card itself.

When I went to reboot I get this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54qFf.jpg)

Comment: Considering your admitted lack of experience and the assumed critical nature of the data, it might behoove you to hire someone to implement a proper storage solution for you as well as an appropriate backup solution.

Comment: I was thinking this as well. I'll leave this as a last resort for now, but I can see things heading that way.